# PHP - push arrays into array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, while-loop

I have created a function that loops through another function, and the other function returns an array. If I loop through the other function four times, I will get four arrays returned but only one per loop. I would like to merge these four arrays into one array inside my new function.

This is the new function:

```
function groups() {
    $b = array();
    $r = 65;
    while ($r <= 69) {
        $b = bookings($r);
        $merge = array_merge($b);
        $r++;
    }
    return $merge;
}
```

This function only returns the bookings for group 69, but I want to get the bookings for 65, 66, 67, 68 and 69. Please help! Sorry if something is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function groups() {
    $merge = array();
    $r = 65;
    while ($r <= 69) {
        $b = bookings($r);
        $merge = array_merge($merge, $b);
        $r++;
    }
    return $merge;
}
```

Comment: This works but I get this error:  PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: You have to define it before the 1st use. I changed your line defining `$b` as its not needed mostly (b$ is defined anyway by writing `$b = bookings($r)`, but $merge 1st use was defined by using not defined `$merge` so i defined it before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may try array_push() function

```
$b = array_push($b, $r);
```